# What is the meaning of キルフェボン?

Tags: meaning, words

キルフェボン好きの人 雑談好きならココにおいで

キルフェボン I dont understand the meaning of this word. The context is the heading of the chatroom. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.quil-fait-bon.com/ Perhaps?

Comment: It is French and not Japanese, so I'll say it here.  It means "What a fine day it is!".

Comment: @l'électeur Can you post as an answer?

Comment: Please at least use google before asking things like this...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the Japanese language. Also it's not likely to be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

キルフェボン（Qu'il fait bon） is a Japanese cake shop’s name.
[https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/キルフェボン](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%9C%E3%83%B3)